# What is a windows bat analog of cd $(dirname $0)?

Tags: bash, batch-file

I've looking pretty long to get answer on this simple question and finally got it. Want to share with those who will port shell scripts to the bat analogs.

Comment: Rather than filler text it would be useful to state what `cd $(dirname $0)?` achieves and why you need an equivalent of it. Your question body is currently meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple solution is:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

`%0` contains the full path of the running .bat or .cmd file.

The `~` expansions can be applied to all numbered arguments (`%0`…`%9`) and to the one-letter variables used by FOR (e.g. `%%a`). The most commonly used expansions are:

- `~d`: drive letter (with colon)
- `~p`: directory path (without drive letter)
- `~n`: file name without extension
- `~x`: file extension (with leading dot)

So combining them into `%~dp0` will work like `dirname`, while `%~nx0` will work like `basename`.

Comment: If you ever find yourself in this situation, better **add an explanation of how the answer works** instead of just some filler text.

Comment: (Also, the simple solution won't work if the script is on a different drive letter than current directry – you'd need `cd /d` or `pushd` to make that work.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer described by @Stand Alone is not completely reliable, because if the script in is another drive rather than current directory, It will not work. So some other solutions are:

### Method 1

```
pushd "%~dp0"
```

### Method 2

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

**Note**: To change directory to the last set directory, `popd` command can be used. This only works after changing the directory using #method 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d "%0\.."
```

Every filename can be used as a dir path ))